# Syntax error while using datediff () in h2 database

Tags: jpa, h2

I got a issue while using datediff() function with H2 database.
Here is the query

```
String FIND_WORK_UNIT_BY_PART_UUID_AND_STATUS = "select new com.altissia.erasmus.domain.WorkUnitCustomObject(workUnit.studyLg," + "(datediff(workUnit.endTime , workUnit.startTime))) from V2WorkUnit workUnit where workUnit.workUnitState.status = 'PENDING' and workUnit.part.uuid =:partUuid order by workUnit.studyLg";
List<WorkUnitCustomObject> workUnitWithLateDays = entityManeger                .createQuery(FIND_WORK_UNIT_BY_PART_UUID_AND_STATUS).setParameter("partUuid", partUuid).getResultList();
```

Here is the exception:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select v2workunit0_.study_lg as col_0_0_, datediff(v2workunit0_.end_time, v2workunit0_.start_time)[*]

Here are JPA properties in application ymll file

```
jpa:
        packages.to.scan: com.altissia.erasmus.domain
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        connection.driver_class: org.h2.Driver
        database: H2
        openInView: false
        show_sql: true
        generate-ddl: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: ""
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: and? datediff does not appear in ANY JPQL manual or documentation for a reason. It is invalid syntax. This is NOT SQL

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#datediff. datediff is supported by H2

Comment: And? As I said this is JPQL you are using NOT SQL. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#functions

Comment: When I am using MySQL for database with data-platform org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect the query is executed well. As I know  JPQL query is translated in SQL query . If you know how to use datediff in h2 databse despite JPA (JPQL) it will be very helpful.

Comment: Use SQL ... aka JPA Native Query. Then it is not JPQL, and so is not invalid. The JPA spec defines what functions are available and it is public so you really need to consult it if you expect your software to be vendor independent

Comment: DATEDIFF works fine in our projects using Sybase. I really can't see a reason to be so harsh in the comments section, plus I would like to know why it's working on MySQL but not on H2.

Comment: Harsh? I state what the JPA spec says about JPQL. The O/P (and many posters on stackoverflow in general) was seemingly not aware that JPQL != SQL. If your JPA vendor (you don't say what vendor) supports DATEDIFF, then you throw away vendor independence, and datastore independence

Comment: ok I fixed syntax exception - diffdate()  function in h2 databese should be used like this :   DATEDIFF('DAY', now() , workUnit.startTime)                      with tree arguments , I was trying to use the function only with two arguments ( first and the second date, that is valid syntax in MySQL)